# "On the Probability of Sequences in the Genoese Lottery" by Euler. How did he do it?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, integer-partitions

This a problem solved by Leonard Euler. Translated English version is available in Euler archives.[E338][On the Probability of Sequences in the Genoese Lottery Euler](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/338/).
I have difficulty in understanding Corollary 2 on page 29 he derived out of the blue. Can any one explain how did he arrive at  the formula for the number of cases of all species which belong to a particular  value of k. Here's an attached screenshot.[image]
I only want explanation of the first factor in those formulas

(m-1),(m-1)(m-2)/2....

Answer (score 1):

You have the numbers $1,2,3,\ldots,n$ and you choose $m$ of them.  There are ${n \choose m}$ ways of doing this, and that is the final expression.

The question is related to how many sequences of consecutive numbers are in the draw, and $k$ measures this here. So if the drawn numbers were $\{3,4,5,6,7\}$ that would count as $k=1$ sequence, while if the drawn numbers were $\{2,5,6,8,9\}$ that would that would count as $k=3$ sequences.

There is a sign error and the $m-k-1$ should be $m-k+1$ so the initial product is ${m-1 \choose k-1}{n-m+1 \choose k}$.  I doubt *species* is a good translation of *especes*; perhaps *types* might work better.

Both the ${m-1 \choose k-1}$ and ${n-m+1 \choose k}$ are *[stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))* calculations.  You want $k-1$ non-empty separators between the sequences and $k$ sequences between the non-drawn numbers, adjusting for the ends of the original set.

In particular the ${m-1 \choose k-1}$ is the number of ways of splitting the $m$ drawn numbers into $k$ sequences, so for example with $m=5$ and $k=2$ we could have $abcd|e$ or $abc|de$ or $ab|cde$ or $a|bcde$ i.e. ${5-1 \choose 2-1}=4$ ways.

Comment: Thank you for explaining but I have few doubts. Euler used an inductive argument to find the second factor so he must have used something like that for first one also ?

Comment: For m=5 and k=2 ,isn't number of split is 2 ?                                                          
  1{4}+1{1} --> a,a+1,a+2,a+3,b  and  1{3}+1{2} --> a,a+1,a+2,b,b+1                         
     page17 of that paper list them

Comment: That earlier section is related to a different question (problem IV in paragraph 14) and different *especes*. By the time Euler reaches the general problem on page 226 in paragraph 24, he says *(1) marque un nombre solitaire* and then in paragraph 26 uses that to calculate $k$; if $a$ is $1$ then he counts $\alpha$.  The *especes* in paragraph 26 are the number of sequences including single-number sequences; earlier they were the lengths of sequences.

Comment: English Translation available here :.https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?filename=0&article=1337&context=euler-works&type=additional

Comment: Thanks Now got it! But Euler doesn't explicitly say anything about using stars and bars calculations he observes few examples and forms an inductive argument. Am I missing something?